# How do I query in Google Bigquery from a table that has Null in a date column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, null

I'm using BigQuery and I'm supposed to query from a table but the table has a date column and part of the values are Nulls.

I receive the following error:

Error while reading table: test.first_spend_day, error message: Could not convert value to date. Error: Invalid date: 'NULL'. Row 3746; Col 3. File: 1mkoqxim8H6TRt20V2Yob9MnF9hC7aUXG4wtzf-jFE20

I tried to cast the column as string and also tried to add a where clause "if not null"

Didn't help

Comment: replace the NULL values with a valid date https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SAFE_CAST()` instead of `CAST()`.

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#safe_casting